# How would I combine two pandas dataframe based on a if one column contains another value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I have two dataframes:

```
df1: 
ID  Location              Project_Code 
1   New York City NY          674539
2   Atlantic City NJ     76538902
3   Orange County CA     27476391
4   Atlantic City NJ     82727637376
5   Atlanta GA           82727637376
```

```
df2: 
Project_ID   Location_City  Project_Code
1            New York       674539
2            Atlantic City  76538902
3            Atlantic City  82727637376
4            Orange County  27476391
5            Atlanta        82727637376
```

I need to combine two df's based on df1.Location & df2.Location_City as well as df1.Project_Code and df2.Project_Code.

The issue I have with joining is that project codes and locations repeat and the only way to distinguish itself is by joining both the location and project code. The other issue I have is that with the Location from df1 and Location_City from df2, they have additional characters(in this case the state) I was wondering if there is a way to merge the location and location_city in a why where they are read so that location is matched with the location city if it contains a value from location city.

Basically how would I get something like New York, NY to be read as New York

Comment: Please include a running script with your attempt. This includes initializing the two dataframes with your sample data. Answers can be based on that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge with left_on and right_on after cleaning the location in df1:

```
df1['Location'] = df1['Location'].str.split(',')[0]

df1.merge(df2, 
      left_on=['Location', 'Project_Code'], 
      right_on=['Location_City', 'Project_Code'], 
      how='left',
      suffixes=['_df1', '_df2'])
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I couldn't strip, would there be way to merge location and location city if location city contains location?

Comment: Updated the original question for ref.

Comment: You need to harmonize the values, otherwise it will not work. You could analyze how the locations are structured, for example put all of them lower case, replace whitespaces with `_` remove the last two chracters and so on. Another way is fuzzy matching e.g. with Levensthein Distance, but this is a topic on its own.